# Mi prueba se congela al querer manipular un datepicker por segunda vez

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Estoy haciendo una prueba con un doble calendario, en el cual tengo que regresar a una fecha en especifico para poder hacer una consulta en la página, mi problema es que una vez que la prueba le da click al botón de regresar una vez, la prueba se "congela" y ya no vuelve a dar click en el botón de regresar fecha.

[image: Doble calendario de la página]

Este es mi metodo el cual utilizo para hacer que la fecha sea escogida:

```
public Tender escogerFechaDobleCalendario(string primerMes, string segundoMes, string primeraFecha, string segundaFecha, int year)
    {
        //Se le da click para iniciar el proceso desplegando el calendario
        cuadroFechaTexto.Click();
        //Recibimos el valor del año y mes en el cual queremos hacer nuestra busqueda
        string targetMonthsYearString = primerMes +" "+year +" "+segundoMes +" "+year;
        //Recibimos de la página el texto del primer mes y año del calendario (izquierda)
        string firstYearPagina = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ui-datepicker-group ui-datepicker-group-first']//span[@class='ui-datepicker-year']")).Text;
        //Primer mes
        string firstMonthPagina = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ui-datepicker-group ui-datepicker-group-first']//span[@class='ui-datepicker-month']")).Text;
        //Mismo proceso pero con el mes y año del segundo calendario (derecha)
        string secondYearPagina = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ui-datepicker-group ui-datepicker-group-last']//span[@class='ui-datepicker-year']")).Text;
        //Segundo mes
        string secondMonthPagina = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ui-datepicker-group ui-datepicker-group-last']//span[@class='ui-datepicker-month']")).Text;

        //Parseamos el año actual para poder hacer la comparación
        int firstYearDatoNum = Int32.Parse(firstYearPagina);
        //Creamos un wait helper para visualizar y también darle a la página tiempo de refresco
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45));
        Console.WriteLine("Primer mes: " + firstMonthPagina + ", segundo mes: " + secondMonthPagina);
        //Creamos un ciclo para posicionarnos en el mes y año que se requiere
        while (primerMes != firstMonthPagina && segundoMes != secondMonthPagina)
        {
            if (year <= firstYearDatoNum)
            {
                previoBtn.Click();
               
            }
            else
            {
                siguienteBtn.Click();
            }
            //Hacemos que espere a que el boton previo sea visible (si uno lo es, ambos lo son)
            
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(previoBtn));
            //Recibimos de la página el texto del primer mes y año del calendario (izquierda)
            firstYearPagina = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ui-datepicker-group ui-datepicker-group-first']//span[@class='ui-datepicker-year']")).Text;
            //Primer mes
             firstMonthPagina = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ui-datepicker-group ui-datepicker-group-first']//span[@class='ui-datepicker-month']")).Text;
            //Mismo proceso pero con el mes y año del segundo calendario (derecha)
             secondYearPagina = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ui-datepicker-group ui-datepicker-group-last']//span[@class='ui-datepicker-year']")).Text;
            //Segundo mes
             secondMonthPagina = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ui-datepicker-group ui-datepicker-group-last']//span[@class='ui-datepicker-month']")).Text;

            Console.WriteLine("Primer mes (actualziado): " + firstMonthPagina + ", segundo mes(actualizado): " + secondMonthPagina);
        }
        //Seleccionamos la primera fecha
        var primeraFechaSelect = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ui-datepicker-group ui-datepicker-group-first']//a[contains(text(),'"+primeraFecha +"')]"));
        primeraFechaSelect.Click();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

        var segundaFechaSelect = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ui-datepicker-group ui-datepicker-group-last']//a[contains(text(),'" + segundaFecha + "')]"));
        segundaFechaSelect.Click();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        //Por ultimo, damos click en boton Done y cerramos el calendario
        btnDone.Click();
        return new Tender(driver);
    }
```

Lo curioso de mi caso, es que si muevo el mouse fisicamente mientras esta escogiendo la fecha, entonces la prueba si llega a la fecha indicada con éxito y la prueba continua, el problema empieza cuando no muevo nada, ya que es cuando la prueba deja de funcionar. Ayer probando y examinando a detalle el método me di cuenta de que una vez que llega al expected conditions la prueba se detiene (me supongo que es porque esta esperando a que el elemento sea clickeable otra vez), pero apenas muevo el mouse aunque sea un pixel el método regresa el calendario un ciclo mas, espero alguien me pueda ayudar a salir de ese bug, muchas gracias.